# Enigma Machine and how it works

Tags: cryptography

After reading the wiki page on Enigma's, I am still confused as to how it works. Are there some sources that run through how the enigma machine works that is easy to follow. Which also gives information about the how codes are encrypted and decrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this (non mathematical) book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385495323), you will certainly find what you want.

Comment: I have actually read this book a while back(~5 years ago). But I do not recollect the details, which is why I posted here hoping someone could help!

Comment: A soft copy of the pages of the book would do too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if these will help you: the NSA published two booklets about the Engima. One is essentially [here](http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/NSA-Enigma.html), and has a nice diagram on how the Enigma encrypts. A PDF of their booklet on the cryptographic mathematics of the Enigma machine can be found [in their website.](http://www.nsa.gov/about/_files/cryptologic_heritage/publications/wwii/engima_cryptographic_mathematics.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://enigmaco.de/_fs/index-enigma.html) we find a simulation (step by step) in Flash for an enigma, that you can play with yourself (change rotors and steckers, see what input corresponds to output).
I think the wheels are non-historical, but the principle of an enigma becomes clearer.
[This site](http://users.telenet.be/d.rijmenants/en/enigmasim.htm) has a Windows program with an exact simulation of an historical machine, which could be nice to play with.[The cryptomuseum site](http://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/enigma/) has a nice overview of historical machines.